# Word document showing strange symbols

Tags: microsoft-word

I wrote a Word document in English. Then I accidently formatted my hard drive, and when I used a data recovery program, that Word document contained strange symbols:

[image]

Is there any chance to get it back to normal?

Answer (score 1):

What you see is typical for corrupted Office files.

It could very well be damaged beyond repair (missing formatting that is specific to Word documents), but you can **try the [Open and Repair](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/open-a-document-after-a-file-corruption-error-47df9d48-2165-4411-a699-1786ac734bc3) function of Office**.
You can do so by opening a document in Word through "File" -> "Open" -> "Browse", navigating to the right file, selecting it, and using the drop-down menu by clicking the arrow next to "Open":

[image: Drop-down menu in the Browse section]

Comment: i tried that but nothing :(